# xamarin: getting multiple latitude and longiitude from database and plot it into map using pin?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, geolocation

I want to get mulitple GPS Coordinates from sqlite database and plot it into a map using Pin.
i did it like this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        MainMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(9.554777, 44.06482),
             Distance.FromKilometers(20)));


        var data = conn.Query<Report_Table>("Select Lat, Longi from Report_Table");
        foreach (var item in data)
        {

            var posi = new Position(item.Lati, item.Longi);
            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Position = posi,
                Label = "Position #",
                Address = "Address # "
            };

            MainMap.Pins.Add(pin);
        }
   }
```

When i run it is not showing any of the marker on the map, what did I miss?

**slite Table**

```
 public class Report_Table
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement,]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Lati { get; set; }
    public double Longi { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that `data` contains a valid set of results?  Your query selects the column `Lat` but the property in your model is `Lati`

Comment: thanks pal! it did work, but  its only showing one marker instead of showing many markers from databse ? @Jason

Comment: again, are you **sure** that your query returns more than one row?  And if it is, is it possible that the markers are clustered too close together for the scale that your map is set to?

Comment: yeah, the markers had the same GPS Coordinates and they were too close together, I tested it in another place and it did finally work. thanks man @Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is. your code is working fine getting mulitple locations, and i think the reason why you're not getting multiple locations is that the locations in your sqlite are more closely together to appear as markers in the map.